# Truncate to 2 decimal places and Notify user

Tags: c++

Been at this for a while but can't seem to get it right. I know to use setprecision() to truncate a value an user inputs but I'm unsure on how to validate it and tell the user "The value was more than 2 decimal places; it is being truncated."

```
void decimalFormat(string &point)
{
int decimal;
decimal = point.find('.');
if(decimal>2)
{
    for(int x= decimal-2; x > 0; x -=2)
        cout<<"Only two decimal places are allowed.  Truncating the remainder..."<< point.erase(x);
}
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

`setprecision()` doesn't actually truncate the user input, it just sets the number of decimal places when you out put the variable.

**For example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

main () {

    float test = 4.556454636382;

    cout << setprecision(11) << test << endl;
    cout << setprecision(8) << test << endl;
    cout << setprecision(2) << test << endl;

    //set precision back up to 11   
    cout << setprecision(11) << test << endl;

}
```

**Results in**

```
4.5564546585
4.5564547
4.6
4.5564546585
```

I don't know if that answers your question, but it's sort of just an explanation of how `setprecision()` is working, because you see it doesn't actually change the value of the test variable (because even after the output is truncated you can still choose to display a precision of 11 again), it just determines what the user sees.

Does that sort of help explain what you were asking?

Comment: Alright, that makes setprecision clear for me but that leaves me back at the beginning. I need to validate the user input and if the user inputs more than 3 decimal places I have to say "I'm truncating the number to 2 decimals" and output the input with 2 decimal places. I'm attempting to use a for loop but no success.

Comment: So you're trying to determine if a number input by the user has more than 2 decimals? Could you post what you did with the for loop? I don't already know how to do that but I can try to help you figure it out. I have a few ideas I can start trying.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

So this is sort of a hack-y way of trying to solve your problem but I think I've figured something out. So here's this code that I think solves your problem and I'm going to try my best to explain it but if you have any questions let me know.

So the variable "test" would pass your 2 decimal standard, but the second variable "test2" wouldn't. So what I did was multiply each of the variables by 1000, meaning that if the original variable had only 2 decimal points the last digit of the resulting number (test * 1000) would be a zero.

Therefore, if you took the remained (%) of any number with 2 decimal digits multiplied by 1,000 it would be zero.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main () {

    float test = 3.14;
    float test2 = 3.145;

    test = test * 1000;
    test2 = test2 * 1000;

    if ((int)test%10 != 0)
        cout << "FALSE" << endl;
    else
        cout << "TRUE" << endl;

    if ((int)test2%10 != 0)
        cout << "FALSE" << endl;
    else
        cout << "TRUE" << endl;

}
```

**Output**

```
TRUE
FALSE
```

**So, for your code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

main () {

    float num;
    float num2;

    cout << "Enter a number (maximum 2 decimal places): ";
    cin >> num;

    num2 = num * 1000;

    if ((int)num2%10 != 0)
        cout << "You have entered a number with more than 2 decimal places, your number is being truncated." << endl;
    else
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << num << endl;


}
```

**Output when I tried it in my terminal**

```
myterminalstuff$ ./dec Enter a number (maximum 2 decimal places): 3.14

3.14 

myterminalstuff$ ./dec Enter a number (maximum 2 decimal places): 3.1456 

You have entered a number with more than 2 decimal places, your number is being truncated.
```

There's probably an easier way to do this, I just don't know it. If you need me to explain any of that better let me know and I'll try my best.

Comment: I just posted my method, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I added another answer that worked when I tested it, it's not using a loop but that should work for you if you put it into your code. I probably didn't do the best job explaining it so if there's anything that doesn't make sense about the remainder (%) thing or any of that let me know.

Comment: Try putting making a new variable (your original variable * 1,000) and adding the conditional if ((int)YOUR_VARIABLE_HERE%10 != 0) thing into your code and let me know if it works when you put in a number with more than 2 decimal places.